# Python regex: excluding square brackets and the text inside

Tags: python, regex, regex-lookarounds

I am trying to write a regex that excludes square brackets and the text inside them.

My sample text looks like this: `'WordA, WordB, WordC, [WordD]'`

I want to match each text item in the string except `'[WordD]'`. I've tried using a negative lookahead, something like... `[A-Z][A-Za-z]+(?!\[[A-Z]+\])` but doing so is still matching the text inside the brackets.

Is negative lookahead the best approach? If so, where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather than a regex, you might consider splitting by commas and then filtering by whether the word starts with `[`:

```
output = [word for word in str.split(', ') if word[0] != '[']
```

If you use a regex, you can match either the beginning of the string, or lookbehind for a space:

```
re.findall(r'(?:^|(?<= ))[A-Z][A-Za-z]+', str)
```

Or you could negative lookahead for `]` at the end, after a word boundary:

```
output = re.findall(r'[A-Z][A-Za-z]+\b(?!\])', str)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be as simple as

```
(\w+),
```

[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/PO3sHi/2)

Retrieve value of Group 1 for desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that maybe you were trying to write some expression similar to:

```
[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z](?=,|$)
```

or,

```
[A-Z][a-z]+[A-Z](?=,|$)
```

#### Test

```
import re


regex = r"[A-Z][a-z]*[A-Z](?=,|$)"
string = """
WordA, WordB, WordC, [WordD]
WordA, WordB, WordC, [WordD], WordE
"""

print(re.findall(regex, string))
```

#### Output

```
['WordA', 'WordB', 'WordC', 'WordA', 'WordB', 'WordC', 'WordE']
```

---

If you wish to simplify/modify/explore the expression, it's been explained on the top right panel of [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/ibCW3i/1/). If you'd like, you can also watch in [this link](https://regex101.com/r/ibCW3i/1/debugger), how it would match against some sample inputs.

---